# Dull paint spots

Tags: paint, texture

We recently painted with Sherwin Williams Interior Acrylic Latex (Super Paint). In some areas we had to putty holes and then used texture spray to match the texture of the wall before painting. Those areas appear more dull when you look at them at certain angles. Everything was painted with the same paint from the same bucket and the same roller. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Did you prime the walls first? I've seen a few magazine articles with the situation you describe and the key seemed to be whether the walls were primed first. FWIW, I have achieved the best finish consistancy using an oil-based primer followed by a latex paint.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in a comment by [RetiredATC](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/151131/retiredatc), If you didn't prime the whole area first, you'll see differences in the sheen of the paint depending on texture and composition of the surface you're painting it onto.  A rough patch or texture will suck up the paint differently than already-painted walls.
Doing a good job of priming (don't skimp on coverage) is the key to having a nice even final texture, as that will give a nice even and consistent surface for the paint to adhere to.

The best I can recommend now is to try a 2nd coat of paint over the whole area, in hopes that the first coat will act as a primer, of sorts, and help even things out more.  It probably won't be perfect, but hopefully better.

As is often said, the key to a good paint job is in preparation.  If you see pros painting, the majority of their time is spent prepping the area to be painted.  They typically only spend a small part of the whole job actually applying paint.